# sense2vec performance improvemets

Tags: nlp, spacy, sense2vec

I am using Sense2Vec (builds upon Spacy, a fantastic NLP library/tool) and testing the similarity between various words.  Unfortunately the performance is quite slow (execution is over a second on a regular MacBook Pro).

Does anyone have a way to speed this up?

Here is the code:

```
term = "dog|NOUN"
sense2vec = Sense2Vec().from_disk("path-to-s2v_reddit_2019_lg")
sims = sense2vec.most_similar(term, n=top)
```

I suspect some caching would speed things, but I am not sure which elements should be cached.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed a way to speed up `Sense2Vec.most_similar`. There is a script available from https://github.com/explosion/sense2vec/blob/master/scripts/06_precompute_cache.py, which precomputes a cache of the nearest neighbors. It will then save that cache with the component on disk, making the data larger but the queries fast. If a query is not covered by the cache, `most_similar` falls back to using the normal computation.